# Setup Outlook application to use custom email that is created on Skype's site

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, skype

I am trying to add an email Account on Outlook application (**Windows 10**) that came with my **Office 365** subscription. But it throws the "Something wrong" error:

> "Something went wrong and Outlook couldn't set up your account. Please
>   try again..."

These are the steps used to create my custom email:

1. I own a domain (say example.com) and I created an account `author@example.com` on that domain.
2. Wanted to use the above created email account on Skype so I went to skype's site and signed up using the **Use your email instead** option.
3. All well and good, Skype working with the new account etc. I then browse to outlook.com and use the same email address above to log in. Logged in successfully, opening the Outlook Mail site.
4. Now I try to setup the Outlook application using the same email address and I am returned with the error above. I then googled and found that I need to "enable" POP/IMAP on Outlook (Settings > Sync) and use the settings from the site to configure the application. I did and tried both POP and then IMAP option in Outlook app setup but the password screen keeps popping up and it doesn't go any further than that.
5. Used a couple of guides online but nothing has worked so far.

What am I missing and how can I resolve this error?

I also noticed that if I go straight to Outlook's site and Sign up for a new account, there is not an option to create an account from an email instead (like on skype's site). I did not understand why it is not possible on this site and on the other (skype) it is.

Also, when I create a custom email on my domain/hosting panel with its own mailbox then I send an email from another account to this email, it is only visible in my own mailbox and not in Outlook's Mail box, why is that?

**EDIT:**

For my issue, I ended up using the pop/smtp settings of the domain/hosting provider (e.g. `mail.example.com`) rather than the ones Outlook provides. I started receiving and able to send emails from Outlook after this change.

Also, reading **@Aidan**'s comment and the change about the [App password](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b) tells me the password prompt issue could be because of that but I did not see any reason to setup the Outlook email now after I saw that I do not receive any email in the Outlook inbox after sending to `author@example.com`.

So, the question regarding why I do not receive emails in the Outlook inbox and keep receiving normally on my domain's mailbox still stands if anyone could shed some light. Even though I am able to send an email from Outlook inbox (web) using `author@example.com`.

Comment: You may try adding your account via: Control Panel > Mail > Email Accounts > Email > New. >>  (did and tried both POP and then IMAP option in Outlook app setup but the password screen keeps popping up and it doesn't go any further than that.) You may need to type your application password ranther than regular password. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b

Comment: @Aidan: Thanks, this change should probably fix the password prompt issue but it will not resolve the issue of missing emails in the Outlook inbox. Please check the edit in my question.